# How does Yelp do "Open now"?

Tags: database, data-structures

How does Yelp store the time information for the businesses and how is it able to query and filter out businesses that are "Open Now" so quickly?
Wouldn't it need some real-time processing parsing the date-day-time info and comparing it with "now".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the day into 30min intervals and create a database index on `(Interval, BusinessID)` (where a sample value for `Interval` would be `08:00-08:30`). Simply store all the open intervals for all businesses.

That was the simple, guaranteed to be working hack solution that anyone can pull off and maintain. It's a good trade-off. You can also do something clever. See the other answer.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a [segment tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree).  It's a data structure for storing intervals in a way that makes querying which all intervals a point belongs to efficiently. The intervals could be just integer intervals, like (2,3), (5,9), (10, 15), etc.,

In the yelp case, they are time intervals that represent working hours of businesses. It's trivial to get the current time with millisecond resolution. For example, in java, you would get System.currentTimeMillis(). Then if you had stored intervals in your segment tree, you could just query what intervals (in turn what businesses) are open at that time (now). In terms of time complexity, you can get this done in O(log n + k) where n is the total number of business in your database and k is the number of businesses that are open now.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this for implementing in Django- https://github.com/AndrewPashkin/pytempo
It implements the logic in jsonb and needs Postgres 9.4